# Box2dWeb missing ApplyLinearImpuse() and ApplyAngularImpulse() methods?

Tags: html, canvas, box2d, box2dweb

I have been trying to get to grips with HTML5 game writing coming from an XNA / Farseer background.

It seems that box2dweb is missing ApplyLinearImpuse() and ApplyAngularImpulse() methods.

I have even looked at the source [here](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/source/browse/trunk/Box2D.js) and it seems to be the case.

Does anyone know why these methods are not provided?

Comment: Probably because they did not exist in the version of Box2D that box2dweb was ported from at the time.

Comment: Thanks iforce2d, I know your site well. Fantastic content!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just now I needed the same thing. Fortunately the implementation or `ApplyAngularImpulse` is very simple. You can add the following to your code to patch it in to box2d:

**Box2Dweb**

```
b2Body.prototype.ApplyAngularImpulse = function(impulse) {
    if (this.IsAwake() == false) {
        this.SetAwake(true);
    }
    this.m_angularVelocity += this.m_invI * impulse;
};
```

**Box2Djs**

```
b2Body.prototype.ApplyAngularImpulse = function(impulse) {
    if (this.IsSleeping() == false)
    {
        this.m_angularVelocity += this.m_invI * impulse;
    }
};
```

In general, to get at features in the C++ version that haven't been ported to the Flash or JavaScript versions, you can have a look at [the original source](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/), and port them over yourself as above. Even if you're not familiar with C++, the code is fairly approachable.